# Chinese writings in Blade Runner movie

Tags: translation, movies

I've tried to find the characters seen in this picture (from a Blade Runner prop), using online Chinese OCR and other online tools but it's a real struggle for someone as clueless as me in Chinese...
(I've found the following characters from the first line : 接着X製品XX部 )

Could someone help me figure what the characters are and, possibly translate it? Coming from an american movie, I wouldn't be surprised if it is a very approximative Chinese.

[image: Blade Runner phone card]

**EDIT:** I feel bad for mistaking Japanese for Chinese, especially because I first thought of Japanese seeing the characters, but Blade Runner's setting being immersed in Chinese culture, I guess I fought my own instinct.

Comment: It looks like Japanese. but we could probably get the meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's Japanese.

接着剤製品営業部

glue - 接着剤

product - 製品

sales department - 営業部

東京都世田谷區玉川台 2 - 33

Tamagawadai (玉川台), Setagaya-ku (世田谷區) in Tokyo 東京都.

https://www.google.com.hk/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=%E6%9D%B1%E4%BA%AC%E9%83%BD%E4%B8%96%E7%94%B0%E8%B0%B7%E5%8D%80%E7%8E%89%E5%B7%9D%E5%8F%B0+2+-+33&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=Z_8hWrnmCvOiX6vkr4gH

Osaka - 大阪

Nagoya - 名古屋

Sendai - 仙台

Hiroshima - 広(廣)島

Comment: It seems that two characters were not exactly the right ones. I don't know how great they make a difference, but I've managed to find them anyway:
世田谷區 -> 世田谷区
大板 -> 大阪

I feel bad for mistaking Japanese for Chinese, especially because I first thought of Japanese seeing the characters, but Blade Runner's setting being immersed in Chinese culture, I guess i fought my own instinct.

Again, thanks a lot for this very helpful answer. :)

Comment: sorry, it's my mistake, rectified now. about 広 (u+5e83), it's a kanji in japanese, with a matched chinese character 廣 (u+5ee3). technically, they have different code point. well, cognitively, one will exchange them equally, depends on the context.

Comment: Oh, did not see the mistake, thanks for the rectification and explanation. :)